# C# access to stack object property

Tags: c#, class, object, properties, stack

How can I access the objects property in this situation?

```
Araba araba = new Araba();
araba.Renk = "mavi";
araba.fiyat = 12345;

// I created this class and it working normally
ArrayTypedStack asd = new ArrayTypedStack(10); 
asd.Push(araba);

object araba2 = asd.Pop();
araba2.  //cant access
```

Comment: what do you mean by you can not access araba2? araba2 is object type so what you are expecting to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are assigning the value of `asd.Pop()` to a variable of the type `object`.

`object` is the root of all objects (all objects inherit from it and can be casted to it) and as such has no real information about what it is. It's just like  any object in real life is a `thing`.

The solution here is to declare the `araba2` as the type `Araba`, that will give you access to all the properties on the next line.

I don't know the implementation of the `ArrayTypedStack` and what the `Pop()` method looks like (it's return type) so it's possible that this will give you an error, saying that it can't convert an object to the type Araba. This is the type safety implemented in .NET. You have to convince .NET that it's of the type `Araba`, this can be by casting

```cs
Araba araba2 = (Araba)asd.Pop();
```

this can still give an error on runtime if the object returned from `Pop()` isn't of the type `Araba`, in this case you can ask .NET to try to cast it, there are serveral options for this:

```cs
object popResult = asd.Pop();
if (popResult is Araba) {
  Araba araba2 = (Araba)popResult;
}

// can be written as follows:
if (popResult is Araba araba3) {
  araba3.fiyat = 65432;
}

// can also be done as follows
Araba araba4 = asd.Pop() as Araba;
if (araba4 != null) {
  araba4.fiyat = 84368;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your *araba2* variable is of type `object`. Thus, regardless of the actual type of the instance it contains,  through the `object` variable *araba2* you can only access members that are provided by the type `object`.

To access members provided by the `Araba` type (and assuming the instance in the *araba2* variable is an instance of type `Araba`), the *araba2* variable itself should be of type `Araba`, or the value of *araba2* needs to be cast as `Araba`.

Thus,

```
var araba2 = asd.Pop();
```

or

```
var araba2 = (Araba) asd.Pop();
```

with the first example code line above requiring that the return type of the *Pop* method is `Araba` (or a type derived from `Araba`). The latter code line example will work regardless of the return type of *Pop* as long as the value returned by *Pop* is an actual `Araba` instance (or is something that is convertible to an `Araba` instance).